# Connect to Mlab with mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mlab

Hi i'm trying to make a simple connection

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://JFalcon:john2522@ds119476.mlab.com:19476/hidonshabat', {useMongoClient: true}, function(err){
    if(err) {
        console.log('Some problem with the connection ' +err);
    } else {
        console.log('The Mongoose connection is ready');
    }
})
```

As you can see this is the url!
Please help me

Comment: What's the error???

Comment: wrong credentials?

Comment: So, what is the problem? Also, when you post questions like this remember to remove your password from the connection string ie `john2522` in this case :D.

Comment: It just for test. But ty
The problem is 
ailed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 502 (Bad Gateway)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please correct as follows

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://<dbuser>:<dbpassword>@ds119476.mlab.com:19476/hidonshabat', 
    {useNewUrlParser: true },function(err)=>{
    {
        if(err) {
            console.log('Some problem with the connection ' +err);
        } else {
            console.log('The Mongoose connection is ready');
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/myapp', **{useNewUrlParser: true}**);
```

From official docs:

> useNewUrlParser - The underlying MongoDB driver has deprecated their
>   current connection string parser. Because this is a major change, they
>   added the useNewUrlParser flag to allow users to fall back to the old
>   parser if they find a bug in the new parser. **You should set
>   useNewUrlParser: true** unless that prevents you from connecting. Note
>   that if you specify useNewUrlParser: true, **you must specify a port in
>   your connection string**, like mongodb://localhost:27017/dbname. The new
>   url parser does not support connection strings that do not have a
>   port, like mongodb://localhost/dbname.

Answer (score 0):

```
var Mongoose=require("mongoose");
var dbURI='mongodb://JFalcon:john2522@ds119476.mlab.com:19476/hidonshabat';
Mangoose.connect(dbURI,function(err){    
    if(err){
    console.log('Some problem with the connection ' +err)   
    } 
    else {
    console.log('The Mongoose connection is ready')  
    }

})
module.exports={Mongoose};
```